# Unable to Update the SCCM Consol

Tags: windows-10, sccm

When I load the SCCM consol on server its 5.0.8577.1000 but consol on my PC is 5.0.7958.1000

Its not giving me option to upgrade.

I can use the consol on server but I cant use it on my PC becasue its saying that Description = "Please upgrade your Admin Console to newer version";

I'm trying to update my PC with new version of consol but i'm not getting any way.

Can you please let me know why I cant upgrade?

SmsAdminUI.log

```
[5, PID:14856][06/25/2018 13:43:07] :System.Management.ManagementException\r\nGeneric failure \r\n at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
at System.Management.ManagementObject.InvokeMethod(String methodName, ManagementBaseObject inParameters, InvokeMethodOptions options)
at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlConnectionManager.ExecuteMethod(String methodClass, String methodName, Dictionary`2 methodParameters, Boolean traceParameters)\r\nManagementException details:
instance of __ExtendedStatus
{
Description = "Please upgrade your Admin Console to newer version";
Operation = "ExecMethod";
ParameterInfo = "SMS_Identification";
ProviderName = "WinMgmt";
StatusCode = 2147749889;
};
```

SCCM info

- OS: 2012 R2
- SCCM 2012 1710

My PC

- Windows 10 1802 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix.
I copy the files from \SCCMSEEVER\SMS_Site\tools\ConsoleSetup to my PC and run the AdminConsole.msi

After doing this all is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem would be that the old console (2012 R2) was updated via a normal package by the server while the new version introduced with the multi annual releases (first version was 1511 I think and current version 1802) uses a self updating console.
So your server probably thinks the console will be self updating and the client thinks the server will update it.

On your site server there should be the full setup for the current console version
On our server there is a share:
\\SMS_\tools\ConsoleSetup (i hope this is universal, the local path from the server would be X:\Roles\ConfigMgr\tools\ConsoleSetup on the partition where your Roles are installed)

I would use this setup to update, or if it also fails to completely uninstall and reinstall the console. From then on it should auto-update with every new release.